# XNA Veiwing cubes behind others

Tags: xna, c#

I am learning 3D at the moment. It is going well but I am stuck on the viewing of the camera.

I have two cubes, one next to each other made up of vertices, all the faces/triangles in the cubes are clockwise vertics so that when you move around the box, only 1 or two sides are visible at once. But, here's the problem, if I look at the cubes from the right, I can see a face of the cube that is further away. Like pictured below,

[image]

What would be the best way to deal with this, and are there any tutorials that could help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your graphics device to do a depth-test to compute which cube is in front of the other cube and to not show parts that should be obstructed.

To do this in XNA add this right before you draw the cubes.

`GraphicsDevice.DepthStensilState = DepthStensilState.Default`

Note that some XNA components, such as the SpriteBatch change your graphics device states. So you need to make sure your graphics device states are correct each frame before you draw  something that depends on it.

Edit: for more info please [see this excellent post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/02/state-objects-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) by our all-time-XNA-god Shawn Hargreaves

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple piece of code. Though I will read the post from Shawn Hargreaves for more understanding :)